# How to output verbose logging from powershell that is being called by an Ansible playbook

Tags: powershell, ansible

I have an ansible playbook, similar to this:

```
        - name: Run Powershell script with Parameters.
          win_shell: MyPS.ps1 -Param1 "{{ Param1 }}"
```

and within the Powershell script I have lots of Write-Verbose and Write-Information calls, like:

```
    [CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$Param1
)

$DebugPreference = "Continue"
$VerbosePreference = "Continue"
$InformationPreference = "Continue"

Write-Verbose "MyVerbose statement"
Write-Information "MyInformation statement"
```

If I run the powershell directly then I get "MyVerbose statement" and "MyInformation statement" outputted however whenever I run this through ansible then only "MyInformation statement" is returned.

I have tried the following:

1. Calling the powershell script with "-Verbose" switch
2. Setting the VerbosePreference to Continue (as you can see above)
3. Redirecting all logging levels using `*>&1` at the end of the powershell call in the ansible playbook

Unfortunately nothing seems to output the verbose logging.

I have also registered a variable with the win_shell output to see if the verbose output is returned in some other attribute but alas it isn't.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: You could append the parameter `-Verbose` to your `Write-Verbose` command to force its output.

Comment: Would that not have the same effect to the -Verbose to the powershell script itself? And/or same result as $VerbosePreference = "Continue"?

Comment: I can't say, except to suspect that something doesn't work right in Ansible with the verbose stream.

Answer (score 1):

Using `[CmdletBinding()]` automatically adds the `-Verbose` parameter to your script (if that line is not inside a function). You probably just need to use it when running your script, and maybe coerce it to stdout:

```
- name: Run Powershell script with Parameters.
  win_shell: $(MyPS.ps1 -Param1 "{{ Param1 }}" -Verbose) 4>&1
```

Check out the examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71143803/7411885

---

I'd also suggest trying the `ansible.windows.win_powershell` module vs `win_shell`: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_powershell_module.html

There is a list of differences in how the module handles output, including a parameter for verbose stream specifically:

> `$Ansible.Verbosity` reveals Ansible’s verbosity level for this play. Allows the script to set VerbosePreference/DebugPreference based on verbosity. Added in `1.9.0`.